# DDr3 or DDR3L for Acer Aspire 5745G

Tags: laptop, memory, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire 5745 G. I am planning to upgrade the RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB.

Specs:
Acer Aspire 5745G 2010 model.
Core i5 430M processor, Acer ZR7 mobo, Intel HM55

Current working RAM: 2*2GB DDR3, 1066, dual channel (2*533)
Spec on the sticker: 2GB 2Rx8 PC3 10600S-09-10-F2

1. Should I get DDR3 or DDR3 L memory?
2. What frequency, 1066, 1333 or 1600

Which one of the following is the better choice:
http://www.amazon.in/Transcend-4GB-DDR3-1066MHz-Noteboo...

OR

http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00B5LOOJG

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

So, a DDR3L would work only if it's 1066 or 1333 and not 1600?

Even then it's better to stick with DDR3, right?

Answer (score 0):

Acer Aspire 5745G supports maximum memory of 8 GB ( 2 x 4 GB)

Recommended memory speed is 1066 MHz (PC3-8500).
Installing faster 1333 MHz (PC3-10600) will operate at 1066 MHz due to Processor's Memory Controller capacity.

Your system works with DDR3, so DDR3L memory will also work, provided they are either DDR3L 1066 MHz or 1333 MHz. Common low voltage memory DDR3L is available at 1600 MHz speed, so it may not be able to under-clock the speed to 1066 MHz. So to avoid all these, go for 1066 MHz PC3-8500 memory.

Refer this link for the 4 GB module compatible with Acer Aspire 5745G:
http://www.memorystock.com/orderitem.asp?it=840ms-840&MnfId=&MdlId=8111026877